# Google play console updating Android app and Wear Os app separately or always together using Multiple Apk?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have made first release of Wear OS apk together with Mobile app apk. Wear Os apk isn't standalone but a companion app.
My questions is if I need to release a new update for Android app but not for Wear Os, should I include both Apks in release or it is enough to release Mobile app apk only.
Also other way around if I want to make a new release on Wear Os apk but I have no chance for Mobile apk. Can I only release Wear Os apk?

When I try with only Mobile Apk in my release and save it and review it.. Play Console shows me a warning icon as shown below. But there is not explanation for it. I am not sure what exactly it means. I googled but couldn't also find anything.

[image]

So my expectation would be here. If i release new version for Mobile apk, but not Wear Os. Wear Os should be still available with the older version or Is it tightly coupled with the same release Mobile Apk ?